# Side by side Basic and Forms Authentication with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, azure, asp.net-web-api

Disclaimer: let me start by saying that I am new to MVC4 + Web Api + Web Services in general + JQuery. I might be attacking this on the wrong angle.

I am trying to build a Web MVC App + Web API in C# for .NET 4 to deploy in Azure. The web api will be used by mobile clients (iOS, using RestKit).

The Web MVC App will be relatively simple. We would like to use Forms Authentication for it and SimpleMembership - which we achieved and works fine.

We'll use the Web API methods from JQuery (Knockout) scripts to fill pieces of the web pages. Therefore, we expect the JQuery to use the same identity authenticated by Forms Authentication.

However, the idea is that the Web Api can be called directly by mobile clients. No Forms Authentications for those.

We have been looking at the Thinktecture Identity Model (http://nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel  https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40). We added the BasicAuth and AcessKey handlers to the config and it works (see code below).

When you try to access the webapi without being authenticated the browser displays the basic authentication dialog and works as expected.

The "issue" is that when you ARE already logged in via Forms Authentication and try to call a Web Api method you still get the Basic Authentication dialog. In other words, Thinktecture IdentityModel seems to ignore the Forms Authentication altogether.

My questions are:

1. Are my expectations correct? that once I have done the forms authentication I shouldn't do anything else to let the JQuery scripts, etc., access the Web API from the same browser user session.
2. How do I fix it?
3. If my expectations are not correct; how is this supposed to work? ie: how do I make the JQuery scripts authenticate?

I know there are tons of similar questions in Stackoverflow, I honestly looked a lot of up, saw videos, etc., but either I am missing something obvious or there is no clear documentation about this for somebody new in the technologies.

I appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
public static AuthenticationConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
{
var config = new AuthenticationConfiguration
        {
            DefaultAuthenticationScheme = "Basic",
            EnableSessionToken = true,
            SetNoRedirectMarker = true
        };            

config.AddBasicAuthentication((userName, password) => userName == password, retainPassword: false);
config.AddAccessKey(token =>
        {
            if (ObfuscatingComparer.IsEqual(token, "accesskey123"))
            {
                return Principal.Create("Custom",
                    new Claim("customerid", "123"),
                    new Claim("email", "foo@customer.com"));
            }

            return null;
        }, AuthenticationOptions.ForQueryString("key"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution for this problem which I have come up with earlier.

> **Note:** This solution doesn't involve Thinktecture Identity Model.

I have an abstract [BasicAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle/blob/dev/src/WebApiDoodle.Web/MessageHandlers/BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs) class which is a delegating handler. You can get this handler by installing the latest stable [WebAPIDoodle NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/WebAPIDoodle).

You can give a hint to this base basic authentication handler to suppress the authentication process if the request has been already authentication (e.g: by forms auth). Your custom handler that you need to register would look like as below:

```
public class MyApplicationAuthHandler : BasicAuthenticationHandler {

    public MyApplicationAuthHandler() 
        : base(suppressIfAlreadyAuthenticated: true) { }

    protected override IPrincipal AuthenticateUser(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        string username, 
        string password, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) { 

        //this method will be called only if the request
        //is not authanticated.

        //If you are using forms auth, this won't be called
        //as you will be authed by the forms auth bofore you hit here
        //and Thread.CurrentPrincipal would be populated.

        //If you aren't authed:
        //Do you auth here and send back an IPrincipal 
        //instance as I do below.

        var membershipService = (IMembershipService)request
            .GetDependencyScope()
            .GetService(typeof(IMembershipService));

        var validUserCtx = membershipService
            .ValidateUser(username, password);

        return validUserCtx.Principal;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthenticatedRequest(UnauthenticatedRequestContext context) {

        // Do nothing here. The Autharization 
        // will be handled by the AuthorizeAttribute.
    }
}
```

As a final step, you will need to apply `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` (not `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`) to your controllers and action methods to give authorization for the specific roles and users.

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, this is good. However, where does the "IMembershipService" interface come from? (it doesn't seem part of the WebAPIDoongle or the standard .NET4 MVC). Note, your class works, I wish the same class also handled API Keys, however, I believe I can add that feature. My main problem right now is how to use the "WebSecurity" class to validation the user against the database and return the Principal (I can do WebSecurity.Login, but that's cheesy).

Comment: BTW: when testing from a browser (Chrome) it doesn't force the browser to provide the Basic Authentication if the user is not logged. While that's not necessary for my mobile clients, it is convenient for testing. I'll check that out too.

Comment: @rufo IMembershipService is my own implementation. I put it there for u to get an idea. You can replace that with ur own impl.

Comment: @rufo here is the [ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle/blob/dev/src/apps/WebAPIDoodle/Http/Handlers/ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.cs). As the source is available for both of them, you can mix those and create your own.

Comment: @rufo if you want that behavior, leave the [HandleUnauthenticatedRequest](https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle/blob/dev/src/apps/WebAPIDoodle/Http/Handlers/BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs#L118) method as it is. As u can see in my sample, I replaced it with my own behavior which does nothing at all and leave the authorization to AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe this has started me up.