# Prevent browser authentication dialog on 401

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I'm running a web-api webservice inside a MVC4 Forms authentication enabled website. The Forms authentication app uses the web-api webservices. 
I've protected the web-api with the [Authorize] attribute. 
Now when I call the web-api from the MVC4 app *while the authorization ticket has expired* I get an ugly browser kind of logon dialog (which doesn't work with forms authentication). 
I'm not getting this on my dev machine (IIS7.5), which I don't really understand!
How can I prevent this dialog to come up? I only need to receive the 401.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Side by side Basic and Forms Authentication with ASP.NET Web API (.Net 4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004091/side-by-side-basic-and-forms-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-net-4)

Comment: Looked at that post and many others but didn't find any solution or explanation why it works on my dev machine and not on server with IIS6.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of AuthorizeAttribute?  You should be using System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute for Web API, NOT System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute. They have very different behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the site to an IIS8 server and now the problem has gone...

Answer (score 0):

John Galloway explain this nicely in his screencast at [ASP.NET Web API - Authorization](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/03/23/asp-net-web-api-screencast-series-part-6-authorization.aspx) (*A highly recommended watch*)

For some api controller like one below, where you have used an `Authorize` attribute on it.

```
[Authorize] 
public class CommentsController : ApiController  
{ 
...
}
```

He says, If a client makes an unauthorized request, the AuthorizationFilter does the only thing that makes sense for an HTTP API - it returns an HTTP Status Code 401, Authorization Required. Again, we're back to the value of using HTTP for an API - we don't need to arrange anything, any client on any platform will know what an HTTP 401 response means.

It's up to the client to decide what to do when they get a 401. In this JavaScript / browser based sample, we'll just redirect to the login page on the client.

```
$(function () { 
$("#getCommentsFormsAuth").click(function () { 
    viewModel.comments([]); 
    $.ajax({ url: "/api/comments", 
        accepts: "application/json", 
        cache: false, 
        statusCode: { 
            200: function(data) { 
                viewModel.comments(data); 
            }, 
            401: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                self.location = '/Account/Login/'; 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
}); 
});
```

Here in the example if 401 is encountered its up to you to decide what has to be done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's already what I'm doing but it still gives me the browser popup. Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/BufLzdHD

Comment: ya, you can change `self.location='/Account/Login/'` and instead insert the behaviour you want here