# WebApiDoodle BasicAuthenticationHandler and WebApi 4 not Allowing Anonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This a .NET 4.5 C# MVC + WebAPI 4 project. I am using the WebApiDoodle 2.0.1  BasicAuthenticationHandler to use MVC + WebAPI side by side security as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004091/side-by-side-basic-and-forms-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api).

In my Application Start I add the Message Handler:

```
globalConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new {MyClass Derived from BasicAuthenticationHandler}());
```

The MVC controllers work fine (classes derived from  `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`).

However, the WebApi controllers (derived from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`) ignore the `System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous` attribute. They basically want to authenticate/authorize everything.

If I remove the custom message handler from the globalConfig the WebAPI works as expected, the AllowAnonymous attribute allows anonymous requests to be served (and actions that have [Authorize] are denied).

Any ideas what might be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like a bug in that MessageHandler

https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle/blob/dev/src/WebApiDoodle.Web/MessageHandlers/BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs

If Authorization header is null, it's returning a challenge (www-challenge), so it never invokes the Web API. The challenge should only be returned if the web api method can not be executed because it requires authorization. It should have something like this,

```
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
.ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(r =>
{
  if (r.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
  {
    return HandleUnauthenticatedRequestImpl(request, cancellationToken);
  }

  return r.Result;
});
```

Ask the project owner if he can fix the handler.

Comment: This works. Thank you. The actual code is in https://github.com/josea/WebAPIDoodle/blob/dev/src/WebApiDoodle.Web/MessageHandlers/BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs. I am going to contact the developer to see if he accepts a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with the developer of WebApiDoodle he suggested a different approach.

You can see detail of the discussion here: https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle/pull/8

Anyways, the important part from the developer:

> AllowAnonymousAttribute has no logic inside it. AuthorizeAttribute honors it. In my personal opinion, every user should authenticate to an API if that API needs authentication. That's why u see this as the default behavior. However, the fix is easy. Just override HandleUnauthenticatedRequest method and keep it empty. Then, add the challenge request as a continuation to your handler's SendAsync method just like you did.